# Best way to find all indexes in a string then using the indexes to edit letters at those positions in another string for Hangman Game

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, indexing

I am stuck at this part of making my hangman game:
For words with multiple same letters, I want the program to match the user input to the word, and then display all instances of that letter (like in regular Hangman).
I created a copy of the target word and replaced all letters with a #, then whenever the user uncovers a letter that copied 'hidden' version slowly changes as letters are found, it worked well with singular letter instances, but not with multiple letters.
The following code is not runnable, as line 24-29 need changing.
I learned about using def() function to help extract multiple indexes from a string, but they get stored in a list and I do not know how to make use of them in that format. I am not good with for loops yet.

So TL;DR: line 24-29 need changing so that all same letter instances get found and then using those indexes to change the hidden word to uncover all found letters for the user to see.

```
 def change_char(s, p, r):
    return s[:p]+r+s[p+1:]

def find(s, ch):
    return [i for i, ltr in enumerate(s) if ltr == ch]
word = "abigail" #Test Word to be guessed
edited_word = word.replace(word,  "#" * len(word)) #making the second copy hidden
guessed_word = edited_word #copied word for uncovering attempt
win = 0
guess = 0
guesses_left = len(word)
print("Good luck! You have {} guesses left. Press ! to quit".format(guesses_left))
print(edited_word)
while win == 0:
    guess = input()
    if len(guess) >= 2: # checking for single inputs only
        print("Valid inputs only! 1 character per guess, no numbers or symbols. Press ! to quit")
        continue
    elif "!" in guess: # checking if user wants to quit
        break
    elif guess.isnumeric(): # checking for numbers
        print("Valid inputs only! 1 character per guess, no numbers or symbols. Press ! to quit")
        continue
    elif word.find(guess) != -1: # if character exists will return index, user guessed a character right!
        # found_letter_index = word.find(guess) |||| this was my original code, it only wqorked with single letter instances
        found_letter_index = find(word, guess) # new attempt that returns indexes but are stored in a  list
        found_letter = word[found_letter_index]
        guessed_word = change_char(guessed_word, found_letter_index, found_letter)
        print("test {}".format(guessed_word)) #test print for trouble shooting
    elif word.find(guess) == -1: # user guessed character wrong
        guesses_left -= 1
        print("Guesses Left: {}".format(guesses_left))
    elif guesses_left == 0: # failed too many times, game exits
        print("You loose, no more guesses left!")
        break
```

This was a project to help me learn more about python, and so far I made it by just googling and reading python docs, so if you could provide an explanation with your answer it would be appreciated and help me greatly!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary filled with single letter as keys and a list of its positions. 
Use a list of `'#'` as hint-giver, and substitute the correct positions if something good was guessed. You do not want to string-slice all the time because strings are immuteables and get trashed / recreated all the time. Lists can change things at an index-position without needing to be recreated/trashed.

The advantage is that you only iterate the word twice (once if you use defaultdict(list) ) - all other "find" operations are simple lookups that take no time at all.

Could look like this:

```
word = "guessme"

# create a dictionary with key:list inputs, use a defaultdict(list) for bonus points
letter_pos = {l:[] for l in word}

# fill the list with the positions
for idx,l in enumerate(word):
    letter_pos[l].append(idx)

# create list with a # for each letter
guessed = ['#' for _ in word]

auto_guess = "qetusmglr"

print(f"Hint: {''.join(guessed)}")

# you need a while True here and the input() mechanics from above
for g in auto_guess:
    print(f"Your guess: {g}") 

    # letter in our dict with positions? 
    if g in letter_pos:
        # iterate all positiones in the list and replace with letter
        for idx in letter_pos[g]:
            guessed[idx] = g
        # delete the letter from the dict
        del letter_pos[g]       

    # use ''.join( ... )  to print the list as string 
    print(f"Found: {''.join(guessed)}")

    # empty dictionary == all letters found
    if not letter_pos:
        break

print("Done")
```

Output:

```
Hint: #######
Your guess: q
Found: #######
Your guess: e
Found: ##e###e
Your guess: t
Found: ##e###e
Your guess: u
Found: #ue###e
Your guess: s
Found: #uess#e
Your guess: m
Found: #uessme
Your guess: g
Found: guessme
Done
```